# Determine percentage of visible control in wpf

Tags: wpf

Is there a way to determine the size and position of the visible area of a control in WPF, when the control is somewhere in a scroll viewer?

I would like to center on the control with that has the highest  percentage of Visible area.

Comment: What do you mean by "center on the control with..."? I am trying to understand, do you have any control in a specific area inside a list which can be scroll and when do you want it to be bigger? When it just be clicked? or viewed?

Comment: I think that is possible. could you post a sample for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved within the constraint of problem. Assuming the width of all controls are the same

```
ScrollViewer viewer = sender as ScrollViewer;
if (viewer == null) return;
    double absOffset = viewer.HorizontalOffset;
    double width = this.controlWidth;
    double relOffset = absOffset / width;
    double position = Math.Round(relOffset);
    viewer.ScrollToOffset(position * this.controlWidth);
```